# how do Find the names of students whose names starts with ‘b’ and ends with ‘y’ (case insensitive)?

Tags: linux, command-line

```
Student Alice Essentials 20 PSAT 22 Maths 34 Cultural 25 English 70
Student Bob Essentials 23 PSAT 21 Maths 32 Cultural 18 English 94
Student Boby Essentials 43 PSAT 31 Maths 22 Cultural 8 English 93
Student Clara Essentials 18 PSAT 16 Maths 27 Cultural 12 English 45
Student Dirck Essentials 25 PSAT 23 Maths 48 Cultural 25 English 98
Student Eve Essentials 08 PSAT 06 Maths 12 Cultural 13 English 05
```

**this the data saved in a file called demo**

**NOW i want to get back the marks of the student whose name starts with b and ends with y**

Comment: Could you show some effort in solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '
Student Alice Essentials 20 PSAT 22 Maths 34 Cultural 25 English 70
Student Bob Essentials 23 PSAT 21 Maths 32 Cultural 18 English 94
Student Boby Essentials 43 PSAT 31 Maths 22 Cultural 8 English 93
Student Clara Essentials 18 PSAT 16 Maths 27 Cultural 12 English 45
Student Dirck Essentials 25 PSAT 23 Maths 48 Cultural 25 English 98
Student Eve Essentials 08 PSAT 06 Maths 12 Cultural 13 English 05' |
```

---

```
 gawk 'NF *=1<NF' FS='^[^ ]+ [Bb][^ ]*[Yy] ' OFS=

 mawk '$0  =  $2' FS='^[^ ]+ [Bb][^ ]*[Yy] '
```

---

```
Essentials 43 PSAT 31 Maths 22 Cultural 8 English 93
```

if you just wanna keep that row, without the trimming :

```
nawk -F'^[^ ]+ [Bb][^ ]*[Yy]' \$2
                                   or simply,
awk '$2 ~ /^[Bb].*[Yy]$/'
```

---

```
Student Boby Essentials 43 PSAT 31 Maths 22 Cultural 8 English 93
```

A ***very fringe*** way of achieving the same effect ::

```
gawk 'tolower(substr($2$2, length($2), 2)) == "yb"'
```

---

```
Student Boby Essentials 43 PSAT 31 Maths 22 Cultural 8 English 93
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your goal by using `awk` which is the command-line tool for data extraction and manipulation.

```
awk 'tolower($2) ~ /^b.*y$/ {for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) printf "%s ", $i; printf "\n"}' demo.txt
```

**NOTE:** The above command only displays student's subjects along with their marks (as per your requirement).

#### Explaination of the above command

- `tolower($2)` converts the second column (student names) to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison.
- `~` is the pattern matching operator in awk.
- `/^b.*y$/` is the pattern we are searching for. It matches any line where the second column starts with 'b' and ends with 'y' (both case-insensitive).
- `{for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) printf "%s ", $i; printf "\n"}` iterates over the columns from the 3rd column (marks) until the last column (NF represents the total number of columns), and prints each column separated by a space. After printing all the columns, a new line is printed.
- `demo.txt` is the name of the file we want to search for the pattern in.

#### Output

as per your given data you can see the follwing output

```
Essentials 43 PSAT 31 Maths 22 Cultural 8 English 93
```

If you want student name you can use the below command

```
awk 'tolower($2) ~ /^b.*y$/ {print $0}' demo.txt
```

#### Output

```
Student Boby Essentials 43 PSAT 31 Maths 22 Cultural 8 English 93
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'match($2,/^B.*y$/)' students.txt 
Student Boby Essentials 43 PSAT 31 Maths 22 Cultural 8 English 93

$ awk 'match($2,/^[bB].*[yY]$/)' students.txt 
Student Boby Essentials 43 PSAT 31 Maths 22 Cultural 8 English 93

$ awk 'match($2,/^[bB].*[yY]$/){$1=$2=""; sub(/ */,""); print}' students.txt 
Essentials 43 PSAT 31 Maths 22 Cultural 8 English 93

$ awk 'match($2,/^[bB].*[yY]$/){gsub(/^([^ ]* ){2}/,""); print}' students.txt
Essentials 43 PSAT 31 Maths 22 Cultural 8 English 93
```